# PhpUnit ignores *some* instructions in its XML configuration file

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, code-coverage

While developing a lib with PHPUnit at every step of the way, everything was fine. Then I pushed this lib online and deleted the folder.

A while later, I cloned a fresh instance of the repository to continue development, ran the exact same PHPUnit binary (globally installed via Composer) in the root folder of the cloned project (so, effectively, reproduced the original conditions), and noticed that even though PHPUnit read the configuration inside the folder (it said so), it ignored some values, namely, to use colors and the target only the `tests` folder. Instead, it did run all my tests and they were all successful, but it generated coverage for the folder the PHPUnit binary is in, and deeper.

I then tried the same, but with a freshly downloaded `phpunit.phar`. This one produced different, but also weird results - it also read the configuration properly, and used colors this time, but ignored `tests` once again. It also generated coverage for the folder it was in (the project's root folder) ignoring the `tests` location in the XML, and instead generating coverage for the `tests` and `vendor` folder as well.

Here is the [phpunit.xml.dist used in both cases](https://gist.github.com/Swader/c3479cd9f3551cdc496b).

[image: Scenario 1: running globally installed PhpUnit]

[image: Scenario 2: running locally downloaded PhpUnit.phar]

What could be the cause of this?
Library in question is [this](https://github.com/Swader/diffbot-php-client), in case you want to run the tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- I was not able to reproduce the problem you described with regards to colors
- I was able to reproduce the problem you described with regards to code coverage and whitelisting. This problem was caused by a bug in PHP_CodeCoverage 2.0.16 that has been fixed in PHP_CodeCoverage 2.0.17